# Selenium webdriver for automating Flutter web application

Tags: flutter, selenium, selenium-webdriver, flutter-web, ui-automation

I want to automate flutter based web application. Can I use selenium webdriver/java for automation. Can anyone used selenium and how it worked with Flutter web application, did you face any blockers or any difficulties?